# Is having a very big datastructure in C a good practice

Tags: c, data-structures

For my application, it is required to have a data structure that encompasses an entity's details. The number of details required to be stored is quite large: around 100-200 integers, 100-200 pointers etc. What should be the ideal design for such a scenario? Is size of a data structure a factor to be considered while designing?

Comment: Don't put it as separate fields in a structure, it's going to be a hairy and unmaintainable mess. You might be okay with dynamically allocate "arrays" of the heap though.

Comment: Is this structure being accessed for multiple processes? How many instances of this structure your platform needs to keep? Is it suffering frequent modifications in the values? Is there any limitation that makes using a DB for that not an option?

Comment: How are these details described in the specification? What you say is a very bad sign, but without further information it is not easy to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Way too broad to be answered. I regrettably cannot yet but I conceptually vote to close (er, put on hold).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all. Structures in C are allocated as solid fragment of memory. You need to keep this in mind.

Huge structures are hard to maintain but easy to compute by processor since all data are near. If you can try to split your big entity into bunch of small structures with meaningful names.

Second. Define what operations will you perform. If for example you need to extensively change 50 integers but rest of data wont be affected maybe it will be better to put those ints in separate structure and in main structure keep only pointer. It will allow you fast swapping data between different instances. On the other hand if you use this object only as DTO and you don't change it heavily it's all right to keep it as continuos fragment of memory because serialization will be faster and easier.

But at least remember that not only you will deal with this code so try to make it readable. Avoid tables to store [X,Y,Z] dimensions. Better use small struct that can be casted to array when it's needed.

And at least know your machine. If it's a small factory controller or part of a plane that is critical maybe best option is to keep it as simple as possible. Read about memory management in this device (it's really useful to know how malloc works (only idea is not enough))

Comment: First of all, there can be only one first of all. :-)

Comment: @Jens thanks, there should be parser for natural language that will point out similar mistakes e.g `:2 First of all already used at line 1 are you thinking of ...`